# extract openstack instances' volume from ceph

Tags: openstack, ceph

I have an OpenStack-kolla environment with the Ceph backend.
I've configured my cinder backend with NFS. I can create a Backup with Cinder from all instances and store them on NFS. In this case, I don't want to change the Cinder backend to the Ceph but I wonder if there is a way to have access to all Instance volumes on the Ceph like a file and then extract/Download those files from ceph.
what exactly I need is, for example, I have an instance with one attached volume. I want to extract this volume from ceph and keep it, and be able to export that volume to another Openstack.
I know that there are some ways to migrate one instance to another Openstack but I want to have access to the Volumes in the Ceph.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you mention NFS, of course there are ways to export rbd images from Ceph with the appropriate keyrings and permissions. Here's an example to export a volume (containing a glance image) to local file:

```
root@control01:~# rbd --id cinder -p volumes export volume-dd40908f-52ff-4f47-bb06-e5976ac63cb4 test-volume
Exporting image: 100% complete...done.

root@control01:~# file test-volume 
test-volume: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

To import an image file into Ceph you can use `rbd import`:

```
root@control01:~# rbd --id cinder import test-volume volumes/test-volume
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/man/8/rbd/) and man pages for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked for me.